# plot theoretic distribution against the real data histogram on one figure

Tags: r

I want to plot the histogram with real data and compare it with a theoretical normal distribution in one plot. But the scale looks different. **Two plots have different scale**

```
# you can generate some ramdom data on ystar which is realy data.    
x<-seq(-4,4,length=200)
    y<-dnorm(x,mean=0, sd=1)
    plot(x,y, type = "l", lwd = 2, xlim = c(-3.5,3.5),ylim=c(0,0.7))
    
    par(new = TRUE)
    hist(ystar,xlim = c(-10,10),freq = FALSE,ylim=c(0,0.7),breaks = 50)
```

[image: My output]

[image: Desired output]

**Desire output**

Comment: One option is using twoord.plot in library(plotrix)

Comment: It was a pretty wonderful typo, but Stackoverflow strives for the questions to be as helpful as the answers.

Comment: @jdobres,thx, it was an auto-correction. A new word learnt today

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `ystar` is a vector, you should change this:

```
y<-dnorm(x,mean=0, sd=1)
```

To:

```
y<-dnorm(x,mean=mean(ystar), sd=sd(ystar))
```

This will produce a distribution function that approximately matches the histogram.

You should then be able to use the same x-limits for both the histogram and the theoretical distribution, which will eliminate the strange overlapping axis labels you have in your current version.